# Why does Type Resolution fail when using SELECT DISTINCT instead of SELECT on PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, select, union, distinct

Here is a minimal reproduction:

```
SELECT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT NULL
```

Fails with:

```
UNION types numeric and text cannot be matched
```

According to the PostgreSQL documentation on [Type Resolution for UNION, CASE, and Related Constructs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/typeconv-union-case.html) and the following chapter on [SELECT Output Columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/typeconv-select.html), the type of `null` should be derived from the preceding select.

In fact it works, if I remove the `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL
```

Why does the `DISTINCT` modifier interfere with type resolution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the `DISTINCT`, the type of the second part of the `UNION ALL` is `unknown`:

```
SELECT pg_typeof(NULL);

 pg_typeof 
-----------
 unknown
(1 row)
```

This gets resolved to `integer`.

If there is a `DISTINCT`, PostgreSQL has to resolve the type of `NULL` earlier on: to eliminate duplicates, it has to know which equality operator to use. Lacking other information, it chooses `text` as the preferred type of the string category.

Then you get the error because `integer` and `text` cannot be reconciled.

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-oper.html) describes the type choice for the equality operator as follows:

> If any input arguments are `unknown`, check the type categories accepted at those argument positions by the remaining candidates. At each position, select the `string` category if any candidate accepts that category. (This bias towards string is appropriate since an unknown-type literal looks like a string.)

Comment: Do you know whether this is an intentional design decision, or a technical limitation of the type resolution engine that could be improved in future releases?

Comment: I'd say that that is required by the implementation and is not likely to change. You can work around it easily by using `SELECT DISTINCT NULL::integer`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The use of DISTINCT was dropped instead, which was questionable anyway.
(The SQL is not written by hand, but generated; so if it is avoidable to deal with the idiosyncrasies of a specific database, this is preferred.)

Comment: Getting rid of `DISTINCT` is always a good move, particularly for performance.